# How do you make Static tool tip with CSS?

Tags: css

How do you draw tool tip with CSS like that one of linkedin.com that wraps "share an update" textbox?To be more clear i just want a simple static tool tip to make it as wrapper for a textbox(so NOT a on hover pop up buble tool tip).Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use an image + [css sliding door method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/): http://static01.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/bg/bg_sharepostmod_567x400.png

You can achieve the same thing without an image by using CSS3 for the rounded corner and background gradient, plus canvas to draw the tip but that would be an overkill, IMHO, and it wouldn't work on some older browsers.

Comment: Thank you,so where do i download the image?

Comment: @katie The image URL is in my answer